# Call to undefined function filter_var()

Tags: php

After transfering my site to another hosting i got this error:

```
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function filter_var() in
 /home/ultrastep/ultrastep.ru/docs/sites/all/modules/q_cart/q_cart.module on line 410
```

PHP version on server is 5.2.10.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: The link provided by @DanLee is dead, find the archived version [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120725113810/http://forum.ivorde.ro/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-filter-var-in-php-script-t39.html).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to have the php module "Filter" installed

Comment: That with PHP 5.2 became part of PHP itself (it's a pre-compilation configuration flag - not a php.ini one).

Comment: Hi, I am currently facing the same issue. How do I get the php module "Filter" installed?

Comment: If Marco is correct, which would explain Nextcloud's docs omission of the requirement for this module, this is not the case in FreeBSD. Installing `php74-filter` will give you the required module.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles upon this like I did, here is the solution I found for Redhat/CentOS:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-cento-linux-install-php-pecl-filter/

Install php-devel
You need to install php-devel to compile php extensions:

`yum install php-devel`

Download php source code
php_pcre.h header file is not includes with php source code 5.1.6, so you need php source code as well. Visit php.net to grab latest version and store to /opt directory. Use lynx and elinks:

`cd /opt`

`elinks http://www.php.net/get/php-5.2.6.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror`

Save php source to code to disk. Next, extract source code:

`tar -jxvf php-5.2.6.tar.bz2`

Download filter extension
Visit pecl extension to grab latest source code for filter:

`cd /opt`
`wget http://pecl.php.net/get/filter-0.11.0.tgz`

Install filter extension
Unrar file:

`tar -jxvf filter-0.11.0.tgz`

`cd filter-0.11.0`

Open logical_filters.c file:

`vi logical_filters.c`

Find line that read as follows:

`include "ext/pcre/php_pcre.h"`

Change to (the absolute path of php_pcre.h is required):

`include "/opt/php-5.2.6/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h"`

Save and close the file. Finally, type the following commands to compile extension:

`phpize`

`./configure`

`make install`

Configure Filter Extension
Type the following command:

`echo 'extension=filter.so' > /etc/php.d/filter.ini`

Restart httpd:

`service httpd restart`

Comment: Please include some info so that this is not a link-only answer.