# php 7.0 Call to undefined function filter_var()

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to use PHPMailer (which I downloaded from GitHub) to send emails from php scripts.

PHPMailer uses the filter_var() php function to validate email addresses and, as far as I can tell, is part of the filters module that has now been incorporated into the core php product (I'm using php 7.0 on Ubuntu).

I've written a simple script to replicate the problem here :-

```
<?php

    if (filter_var('myname@mydomain.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      echo("Correct");
    }
    else {
      echo( "WRONG!!!");
    }

?>
```

I get the following error message :-

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function filter_var() in test2.php on line 3
```

Grateful of someone can point out what I'm missing.

Comment: [This](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.setup.php) may or may not help. I believe it comes enabled by default so ensure that it is in fact still enabled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735538/call-to-undefined-function-filter-var

Comment: You need install to the PHP module "Filter"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.setup.php

Comment: Hi Praveen, yes I read this too, but in php 7.0 the filter module is supposed to be included in the core of php. If I run php -m I can see filter in the list of modules.

Comment: Nightmare, I have found that the application we use on this server has it's own version of php that is uses instead of the standard version on the server. This is an older version that does need the module installed. Praveen if you add your comment as an answer I can accept it. Thanks to all who commented.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your php.ini file

D:\xampp\php\php.ini

[filter]
; http://php.net/filter.default

;filter.default = unsafe_raw

; http://php.net/filter.default-flags

;filter.default_flags =